# How to pre-Load all the images in GridView?- Android

Tags: android, image, gridview

I have a Gridview in my app but the problem is it loads all the images again as i scroll resulting in serious lags, How can                                                                            i make it load all the images at once and cache it?

```
    package com.example.helloworld;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

  // Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
  mContext = c;
  }

public int getCount() {
  return mThumbIds.length;
 }

public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
 }

public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

  // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ImageView imageView;
  if (convertView == null) {
  imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
  } else {
  imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
  }

  imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
  return imageView;
   }

   // Keep all Images in array
  public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
  R.drawable.sample_0, 
  R.drawable.sample_1,
  R.drawable.sample_2, 
  R.drawable.sample_3,
  R.drawable.sample_4, 
  R.drawable.sample_5,
  R.drawable.sample_6, 
  R.drawable.sample_7,
  R.drawable.sample_8, 
  R.drawable.sample_9,
  R.drawable.sample_10, 
  R.drawable.sample_11,
  R.drawable.sample_12, 
  R.drawable.sample_13,
  R.drawable.sample_14, 
  R.drawable.sample_15,
  R.drawable.sample_16, 
  R.drawable.sample_17  

  };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the method [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) it says it may cause slowness in the UI. The documentation offers an alternative: use setImageDrawable. The second thing is, it seems that the ImageAdapter calls the setImageResource method for the ImageViews every time the GridView is scrolled, instead of just once when the GridView is generated. You can solve that by increasing the scope of the image array. This works well in this case because the GridView always has the same number of elements as defined by the mThumbIds array.

Examples:

To have all the images generated only once, add an Drawable array to the class, and have it be filled during construction:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    // Added drawable array:
    private Drawable[] mDrawables;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

        mContext = c;

        // Fill in drawables with the images:
        for (int i = 0; i < mThumbIds.length; i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mThumbIds[i]);
        mDrawables[i] = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmap);
        }
    } `
```

Now, all you have to do is change setImageResource for setImageDrawable and pass the members of the mDrawables array:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // Changed to setImageDrawable:
    imageView.setImageDrawable(mDrawables[pposition]);
    return imageView;
}
```

The result is that the images will be loaded into Drawables only once and stored, and the setImageDrawable will have faster access to those images, fixing the scrolling.